# Disable caching and get fresh data without detaching entity

Tags: caching, doctrine-orm

**TL;DR: I'm looking for way to partially or fully disable Doctrine caching.**

I'm trying to get fresh data from database, and first I didn't know about Doctrine was it has some sort of cache, how it works, it will not fetch data from database two times.

(It may be more complicated than that, but that how I understand it and that how it works for me, I'm not here to explain how it works, I'm here because I have problem with such mechanics of Doctrine.)

So for example let's say I have code (I work under Symfony):

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$repo = $this-getRepository('AppBundle:User');

$user = $repo->getUserById(1);

echo $user->getName(); // It will print "User"

sleep(5); // I give myself some time to change user name to anything else than "User"

$sameUser = $repo->getUserById(1);
echo $sameUser->getName(); // It still prints out "User"
```

Now to wrok around it I had to user **$em->detach($user)** and only after that $sameUser was containing fersh data fetched from database. I had hope in **useResultCache** and **useQueryCache**, I tried to set those to false on built query, but it doesn't help. It would be perfect to partially disable cache for single queries.

But let's say I have **entity A** that references one of its instance, so for example **userA** has field that points to **userB** by Referer field.

When I detach **userB** to fetch it freshly from database, not from cache, I will get what I wanted but If I will try to save **userA** when **userB** has been detached, Doctrine will complain that it cannot cascade persist referrer field which **userB** is, but it was detached, so Doctrine thinks that referrer of **userA** is new entity (In fact it is detached userB) and to make it work again, I have to set it back, example:

```
$userA = $repo->getUserById(1);

$userB = $userA->getReferrer();
$em->detach($userB);
$userBAgain = $repo->getUserById($userB->getId());

$userA->setRferrer($userBAgain); //Without this doctrine thinks that userA has new entity that haven't been persisted yet.
$em->flush();
```

Ok, so I have workaround and all is great, but is there anything I can do so I get same result without using detach or refresh on entity? I ask because I keep find myself in pitfalls that I didn't predict. Example of such pitfall is:

```
$admin = $this->getUser(); //is current logged user
// it always exists there even if I don't use **getUser** method.
// This currently logged user is an admin, and it is Referrer of $user

$user = $payment->getUser(); //User, currently logged admin is referrer.
$em->detach($user); // Detached
$user = $repo->getUserById($user->getId()); //Fetch fresh data.
$payment->setUser($user); // Set it back so...
$em->flush() // ...So Doctrine won't complain about it when you save payment.
```

Now it may looks easy, but I didn't predicted that when I detached user of some payment which I happened to be referrer of, it also detached form current logged user (**$admin**) and when I flushed, it tried to save **$admin** AND **$payment**, but $admin instance referred to $user instance that has been detached and it thinks it is new instance to be persist. One way to work around it is to detach current logged user, or set **$user** back to **$admin** too, just like I did with **$payment**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can update single entity with $entityManager->refresh($entity)

> Refreshes the persistent state of an entity from the database, overriding any local changes that have not yet been persisted.

or use [Query::HINT_REFRESH](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#query-hints) in your DQL query:

```
public function getUserById()
{
    return $this->em->createQuery('SELECT u, g FROM MyBundle:User u LEFT JOIN u.groups g WHERE u.id = 3')
        ->setHint(Query::HINT_REFRESH, true)
        ->getResult();
}
```

Comment: But it only gets entity by id without joins that been made by original query. But now since I have used some detaching I think refresh would be better choice, less troubles with persistence.

Comment: Is there any way to check if refresh was successful? I tried to remove entity from database and refresh doesn't complain about it at all. It just doesn't refresh.

Comment: Update my answer, try use HINT_REFRESH.

Comment: That works great, it works as I thought useResultCache(false) will work. And not like plain refresh, it does return null when entity is missing. Thanks.